# Getting text from table cell from one View controller to another View controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

having trouble getting a cell that is tapped and has a checkmark to send the cell text to another View Controller

here is my code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

}
```

I also have this inside a IBAction when the View Controller is dismissed:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

((FSPhotoProcessViewController *)self.presentingViewController).categoryResult.text = cell.textLabel.text;
```

When i press the button the app crashes, but if i comment out the presentingViewController line out, then its fine.

```
[UITabBarController categoryResult]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

wondering how to get the tapped cell text to another view

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to dismiss the view controller? You could just load the other one on top of it and then dismiss the new view controller to come back to where you are.

I had a similar problem and dismissing the main view controller was the issue.

Comment: yeah i have the functionality to dismiss the VC.

what i need help in is that when i tap on a cell in the table view, i want the cell's text to go to a UILabel in another VC.

Comment: is the variable 'category' existing beyond your first nslog?  Can you do an nslog just before you have the fsphotoprocessviewcontroller setup?

Comment: i have 'category' as a nsstring within interface and end

Comment: i keep getting this when i use 

`((FSPhotoProcessViewController *)self.presentingViewController).categoryResult.text = cell.labelText.text;`

categoryResult is a UILabel where i want the cell text to go 

Here is the error:

`[UITabBarController categoryResult]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Ah, are you sure that you have a path setup between the two views? I don't think this is a variable problem the issue appears to be your view controllers. Looks like you are switching between some tab bar controllers. Do something like this if you are going to another tab bar view    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];  (0 is first one, 1 is second etc)

Comment: yeah i have a modal segue between the two controllers, and once im on the second controller i use 
`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass texts as NSStrings(create a property in your destination view controller) and then in the viewWillAppear part of destination view controller you need to set UI parts from that NSString property. This error occurs before you destination view controller's UI parts are not implemented until segue call. Therefore you want to pass NSString to UI objects text property but you UI object is not created in the memory.

Example:

```
((FSPhotoProcessViewController *)self.presentingViewController).myStringProperty = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Note: You can also pass numbers,arrays, dictionaries and your custom objects(not UI related).

Comment: when you mean desintation view controller do you mean the initial view controller? or the second one. 
i want the text to come back into the initial.

Comment: i use 
`((FSPhotoProcessViewController *)self.presentingViewController).categoryResult.text = cell.textLabel.text;` to get the text and `categoryResult.text` is a uilabel in my first view

Comment: i get this error `[UITabBarController categoryResult]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: You cannot call UILabel if it's view controller didn't created it properly(which happens after viewdidload called.) Therefore, create another NSString property on that FSPhotoProcessViewController and fill it with proper text **and then** in the FSPhotoProcessViewController's viewwillappear method fill your UILabel with your property string.

Comment: i dont really understand, could you elaborate with some code?